# How to push_back elements of a vector of pointers to struct?

Tags: c++, stdvector

Below is the relevant snippet from my C++ code that is showing a warning `extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x`

```
typedef struct _A{
    string A1;
    int A2;
} A;

vector <A*> vecA;

string str1;
int k;

vecA.push_back(new A({str1, k}));
```

Is there another more proper way of doing a push_back?

Comment: It's not the `push_pack` the compiler complains about but the initializer list `{str1,k}`.

Comment: Add a constructor for the struct. Call the constructor when pushing a new object.

Comment: @jogojapan, yes.. What is the correct syntax?

Comment: @user13107 as billz says in the answer. On a separate note, do you really need a vector of pointers? Your struct is very small and no polymorphism is used, wouldn't a `vector<A>` make more sense than a `vector<A*>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compile with the option `-std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x` when you use `initializer list`, or you could write a constructor

```
struct A {
    A(const std::string& a1, int a2)
      : A1(a1), A2(a2)
    { }

    string A1;
    int A2;
};

vecA.push_back(new A(str1, k));
```

Side note: don't name your type start with underscore, also using smart pointers in vector is a better solution than naked pointer, say:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> vecA;
```

Normally storing values in the vector is quite convenient:

```
std:vector<A> vecA;
```

Comment: For using `std::unique_ptr` you'll also need `-std=c++0x` (or `-std=c++11x` with newer versions), and `include <memory>`.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I am not sure why I was using vector pointers, I'll see if I can do w/o them. I will look into smart pointers. Why do you advice against using underscores here?

Comment: library variable names normally start with underscore, you may get conflict.

Comment: @user13107 Not only do library names start with underscore, the standard says names starting with underscore are reserved for the implementation. So it is actually against the rules.